# Hardened address generation with BIP44 watch-only wallet with xpub

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, p2sh, xpub, bcoin

I am puzzled by the hardened key derivation from a watch-only BIP44 wallet.

Let me first explain what I am trying to do.

- I am implementing a 2-of-3 multisig scheme
- I am using Bcoin node and wallet
- All 3 keys are externally generated
- I want to use Bcoin watch-only wallet

ts to create addresses and scripts

**This is what I have done so far:**

1. Created 3 xprv keys and xpubs keys using this tool [here](https://bip32jp.github.io/english/index.html)
2. I used custome path `m/44'/0'/0'` to have hardened keys because Bcoin wallet requires BIP44 hardened keys
3. I created 3 **watch-only** wallets using the `xpub` keys.
4. Then I added each of the keys as shared keys to each other (I only really have to do this for one wallet)

The code is as below:

```
const HSM_accountKey = "xpub_HSM...."
const IC_accountKey = "xpub_IC..."
const Paper_accountKey = "xpub_Paper..."

const result_wallet_HSM = await walletClient.createWallet('wallet_HSM', options_wallet);
const result_wallet_IC = await walletClient.createWallet('wallet_IC', options_wallet);
const result_wallet_Paper = await walletClient.createWallet('wallet_Paper', options_wallet);


const wallet_IC_account = await wallet_IC.getAccount('default');
const wallet_Paper_account = await wallet_Paper.getAccount('default');
const result_addkey1 = await wallet_HSM.addSharedKey('default', wallet_IC_account.accountKey);
const result_addkey2 = await wallet_HSM.addSharedKey('default', wallet_Paper_account.accountKey);
```

Now I have created a watch-only 2-of-3 multisig wallet.
What I want to do now is to create addresses. I do not want to derive more child extended keys. I only need one derivation level.
Now I want to create multisig addresses for my users.

```
// Create addresses from each wallet
const wallet_HSM_address = await wallet_HSM.createAddress('default');
const wallet_IC_address = await wallet_IC.createAddress('default');
const wallet_Paper_address = await wallet_Paper.createAddress('default');

// Keyrings for script generation
const keyring_HSM = KeyRing.fromJSON(wallet_HSM_address);
const keyring_IC = KeyRing.fromJSON(wallet_IC_address);
const keyring_Paper = KeyRing.fromJSON(wallet_Paper_address);

//Get the pubkeys from each wallet
const pubKeys = [keyring_HSM.publicKey, keyring_HSM.publicKey, keyring_Paper.publicKey];

const multiSigScript = Script.fromMultisig(m, n, pubKeys);
const receivingAddress = multiSigScript.getAddress().toBase58(network);
```

I have a feeling that I am going about this step in a round-about way but you get what I am trying to do.

To re-state, what I want to do now is to create individual receiving addresses for my users and the corresponding P2SH scripts.

Now, this is what **I need help understanding**.

- According to BIP32, you cannot derive hardened public keys with CDKpub. You need the xprv to derive child keys.
- However, from what I have done, I can derive child public keys. I have sent tesetnet coins to these addresses (`receivingAddress` in the code above) and they work. The wallet receives coins.
- How then, was the watch-only wallet able to create hardened child public keys? I did not input `xprv` to the wallet.
- Or, is it that I am NOT creating hardened child public keys when I used the path `m/44'/0'/0'`? 
  Is the `receivingAddress` I am creating in the above code not a hardened one? Meaning that if someone is able to find the child private keys of one user and the `xpub`, they will be able to derive all the chile private keys?

My apologies for the long question. I am a bit confused as to how the wallets are able to create child public keys without having any private key in the wallet.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are deriving child keys. All I see is that you've generated 3 private/public keypairs and made a multisig out of them. That's nothing special.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. What is the difference between deriving child keys and generating child keys? What I am trying to do is to generate child keys for users of the system for them to have a receiving address. What is my misunderstanding? And then later on I need to generate the corresponding child private keys to spend the coins received to those address. So I want to be able to generate those private keys from the index.

Comment: deriving child keys and generating child keys mean the same thing. But, AFAICT, you aren't doing that in your code at all.

Comment: @AndrewChow Thanks so much. Could you kindly tell me what it is happening at `createAddress()`? Is it not generating a child key? Each time I call `createAddress()` it generates a new child address with a certain index. What am I misunderstanding here.

Comment: I was not aware that `createAddress()` is creating a new address. If that is the case, it is not deriving hardened addresses, especially if you only gave it an xpub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not deriving hardened child keys. You cannot derive hardened keys from an xpub. Just because the xpub itself is hardened does not mean that its children are.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That is probably the reason. If you have idea how to explicitly generate hardened child keys please share.